# How to get Form-Data details having SAML Response under header section of network tab from Browser in angular 8 application?

Tags: java, angular, saml, idp

I am trying to do IDP authentication in angular 8 application.so my angular application first redirect to idp server and then idp server gives me SAML response for further authorization.This SAML response is available in network tab of browser under form data section.I want to get this SAML response in my angular application to get my id and email details for further decoding it and using it same for authorization.so my question is, how can i get SAML response from browser and use same in angular app.Please help.I am able to see my SAML response in network tab of browser under header tab having form Data section.
[image]

Comment: Hi did you get any luck ? I am also trying to do the same,, if you had any solution please share

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by writing a index.jsp file in my angular project

```
<%
     String uiBaseUrl = "/ngApp";
     String samlResponse = request.getParameter("SAMLResponse");
     if (samlResponse == null) {
         String error = request.getParameter("error");
         String error_description = request.getParameter("error_description");
 %>
        <script>
            let url = '<%= uiBaseUrl %>' + '/?error='+encodeURIComponent(error)+'&error_description='+encodeURIComponent(error_description);
            window.location.href = url;
        </script>
 <% } else { %>
        <script>
            redirectToUI();
            function redirectToUI() {
                const samlResponse = '<%=samlResponse%>';
                localStorage.setItem('SAMLResponse', samlResponse);
                let url = '<%= uiBaseUrl %>';
                window.location.href = url;
                /*This will navigate to ng App base route with SAMLResponse in localStorage. Write logic in base route component to read this response*/
            }
        </script>
 <% } %>
```